# XSL format-number() returns "NaN" in one environment but not another

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XSL that formats a value to a number

Using the same XSL file, one environment (dev) returns a blank value (as required) but the other environment (test) returns "NaN"

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(XML/XMLData/OptionsPanel/Current/Row/Amounts,'##.0')"/>&#37;</td>
```

What should I be looking for to find out why they are different?

Comment: Show us the whole XSLT and the input..

Comment: I'm unable to get a handle on the XML as it is generated by a third party and I cannot get to it before it processes - all I know is that the exact same XML file is used so there is no difference in the input. Also, no difference at all between the XSLT files - what would you be looking for with the entire XSLT file (it is large)?

Comment: Put in an `<xsl:value-of select="XML/XMLData/OptionsPanel/Current/Row/Amounts"/>` to check whether the value you are trying to format really is a number. Which value do you expect in there that would return "a blank value"?

Comment: Oh, and tell us which two XSLT processors are producing different output.

Comment: @MichaelKay, adding the <xsl:copy-of select="/"/> returns <xml XMLDocument="[object]"/> - instead of showing the XML

Comment: Then your XML document is very different from what you thought it was, so you need to find out why. You're saying you can't "get a handle on the XML" and this seems to be the cause of your trouble: the XML is not what you think it is.

Comment: @MichaelKay - thanks so muh Michael - you were completely correct. Deep down in the XML, the code that produces it was creating a NULL SQL value which is therefore not creating an element (using the FOR XML syntax) Therefore the format-number() was erroring because the element did not exist